# C# Get real tabindex order on winform

Tags: c#, winforms, tabindex

I'm trying to iterate through a list of controls by tabindex.  But there are multiple controls within groupboxes, panels, etc that each start with 1, 2, etc.  I set the order through the standard View-> TabOrder menu option.

```
IEnumerable<Control> cons = dxErrorHandler.GetControlsWithError();
foreach (Control ctl in cons.OrderBy(c => c.TabIndex))
    sb.AppendLine(dxErrorHandler.GetError(ctl));
```

This goes by e.g. Panel1.TabIndex 1, Panel2.TabIndex 1 instead of
Panel1, TabIndex 1.1, Panel1, TabIndex 1.2, etc.

How can I iterate through controls in the same order set in View-> TabOrder

Thank you.

Comment: You can order by Parent then by TabIndex. Or GroupBy Parent and OrderBy TabIndex etc.

Comment: Not sure how to write that out.  Not all controls belong to containers thus no Parent.

Comment: **All** Controls belong to a container, except the Form itself (TopLevelControl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jimi's answer worked.  Didn't realize all controls belong to a "Parent".  Nice to learns something new.

Thanks Jimi!

Comment: Should have added the code...            foreach (Control ctl in cons
                .OrderBy(c => c.Parent.TabIndex).ThenBy(c => c.TabIndex))